# React Native Zomato API reviews not being displayed

Tags: react-native, zomato-api

I am trying to display review information from the Zomato `API` however for some reason nothing is being displayed.

I am using a `FlatList` to put it all out there, but every time I compile the code nothing seems to show up.

Here is all my code regarding the subject:

```
<Text>REVIEWS:</Text>
            {this.state.data.all_reviews_count == 0 ?
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20, marginTop:0}}>
                  <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>No reviews for this restaurant yet</Text>
                </View> :
        <FlatList
                  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => 
                  <View>
                    <Text>{item.all_reviews_count}</Text>
                  </View>}/>}
```

I have other data being retrieved and it's all being outputted just fine. for some reason the review section seems to be weird.

I also checked to see how reviews are displayed in the `terminal` and this is what I got:

```
 "all_reviews": Object {
    "reviews": Array [
      Object {
        "review": Array [],
      },
      Object {
        "review": Array [],
      },
      Object {
        "review": Array [],
      },
      Object {
        "review": Array [],
      },
      Object {
        "review": Array [],
      },
    ],
  }
```

hopefully somebody with experience with the Zomato Api can help me out

Comment: did you try the below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you retrieve & display data is wrong. Check below sample

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Example extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            all_reviews: {}
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            let result = await axios.request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/reviews?res_id=16774318",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'user-key': "af26b7a0e16fb73e6a30ad33cb9c6634",
                },
            })
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                all_reviews: result.data
            })
        } catch (err) {
            err => console.log(err)
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {
                    this.state.isLoading ?
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                            <ActivityIndicator />
                        </View> :
                        <View>
                            <Text>REVIEWS:</Text>
                            {
                                this.state.all_reviews.user_reviews.length == 0 ?
                                    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20, marginTop: 0 }}>
                                        <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>No reviews for this restaurant yet</Text>
                                    </View> :
                                    <FlatList
                                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                        data={this.state.all_reviews.user_reviews}
                                        renderItem={({ item }) =>
                                            <View>
                                                <Text>{item.review.rating}</Text>
                                            </View>}
                                    />
                            }
                        </View>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Change this code according to your requirements & if you have doubts feel free to ask.

Hope this helps you.